# How to optimally use the Windows machines as Jmeter Slaves for pushing higher loads

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, distributed-testing

Greetings for the day!

I am currently facing challenges to induce higher load using Jmeter Distributed mechanism which I configured in AWS windows machines.

My machines are throwing **Response code:Non HTTP response code: java.net.BindException
Response message:Non HTTP response message: Address already in use: connect** exceptions.

I am trying to calculate the foot print for the slave machines so that I can confidently communicate on how much load they can handle.

I am using a windows 2019 server, with a 16 GB RAM.
While surfing through internet for answers I got the below link which says to change the registry settings to optimally use the ports.
https://www.baselogic.com/2011/11/23/solved-java-net-bindexception-address-use-connect-issue-windows/

I am looking for suggestions from your end to execute more threads seamlessly (especially spikes using free from arrival thread groups) from the available resources I am currently having.

Please let me know if any further information is required from my end which can help me get better solutions.

Many Thanks for your support.

Regards,
Vijay

Comment: Does it work with small number of threads?

Comment: Yes.. Smaller loads are running fine..

Answer (score 1):

1. As per [Adjusting TCP Settings for Heavy Load on Windows](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26180_01/Search.94/ATGSearchAdmin/html/s1207adjustingtcpsettingsforheavyload01.html) article you should:

   - create a DWORD value named `TcpTimedWaitDelay` with the value of `60` under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\ Services\TCPIP\Parameters`
   - create a DWORD value named `MaxUserPort` with the value of `32768` under the same key
2. Make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
3. Make sure to monitor the networking and other performance counters of the Windows machine using either built-in Windows [perfmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/perfmon) or via [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri T, for the suggestion. Will try it and update on this thread :)